# NSClickGestureRecognizer not working on NSStatusItem

Tags: macos, swift, osx-yosemite, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

Trying to recognize a right click on a `NSStatusItem` I got a suggestion ( *Thanks* *to* *Zoff* *Dino* ) to use a `NSClickGestureRecognizer` for that. But for some bizarre reason it isn't working as it should be. I am able to recognize a left click (`buttonMask = 0x1`) but not a right-click (`buttonMask = 0x2`). This is how I would like it to work but it isn't:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application


    if let button = statusItem.button {

        // Add right click functionality
        let gesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer()
        gesture.buttonMask = 0x2 // right mouse
        gesture.target = self
        gesture.action = "rightClickAction:"
        button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)


    }}

func rightClickAction(sender: NSGestureRecognizer) {
    if let button = sender.view as? NSButton {
        NSLog("rightClick")
    }
}
```

> #### UPDATE:
>
> I still did not manage to gets to work. Somehow it doesn't react on a right click (but changing the code on a left click) does. I guess some really simple issues are occurring that seem to block it from working. Even stranger is the fact that `gesture.buttonMask = 0x1` works on the left click.

Comment: you need to set the number of clicks required `.numberofclicksrequired`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution rather than `NSClickGestureRecognizer` is to attach a custom view to the status bar and handle the event from there.

The small disadvantage is you have to take care of the drawing and menu delegate methods.

Here a simple example:

Create a file `StatusItemView` a subclass of `NSView`

```
import Cocoa

class StatusItemView: NSView, NSMenuDelegate {

  //MARK: - Variables

  weak var statusItem : NSStatusItem!
  var menuVisible = false

  var image : NSImage! {
    didSet {
      if image != nil {
        statusItem.length = image.size.width
        needsDisplay = true
      }
    }
  }

  //MARK: - Override functions

  override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if let hasMenu = menu {
      hasMenu.delegate = self
      statusItem.popUpStatusItemMenu(hasMenu)
      needsDisplay = true
    }
  }

  override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    Swift.print(theEvent)
  }

  //MARK: - NSMenuDelegate

  func menuWillOpen(menu: NSMenu) {
    menuVisible = true
    needsDisplay = true
  }

  func menuDidClose(menu: NSMenu) {
    menuVisible = false
    menu.delegate = nil
    needsDisplay = true
  }

  //MARK: - DrawRect

  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    statusItem.drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect(bounds, withHighlight:menuVisible)
    let origin = NSMakePoint(2.0, 3.0) // adjust origin if necessary
    image?.drawAtPoint(origin, fromRect: dirtyRect, operation: .CompositeSourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
  }
}
```

In `AppDelegate` you need a reference to the custom menu and an instance variable for the `NSStatusItem` instance

```
 @IBOutlet weak var menu : NSMenu!
 var statusItem : NSStatusItem!
```

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` create the view and attach it to the status item. Be aware to set the image of the view after attaching it to make sure the width is considered.

```
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1) // NSVariableStatusItemLength)
    let statusItemView = StatusItemView(frame: NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: statusItem.length, height: 22.0))
    statusItemView.statusItem = statusItem;
    statusItemView.menu = menu
    statusItem.view = statusItemView
    statusItemView.image = NSImage(named: NSImageNameStatusAvailable)
  }
```

The special case control-click to trigger the right-click function is not implemented.

Comment: Everything seems to be working(thanks for that). But I would like to use an image instead of the title. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want no title at all? I could update the post to use an image instead of a title

Comment: Done. You might scale the image. The `origin` variable in `drawRect` is for fine adjustment of the origin point.

Comment: Ok thanks! You really helped me out!! I will mark your answer as solved :) And of course you will receive the bounty!

Comment: Now setting custom view for NSStatusItem is marked as deprecated, however right click gesture recognizer still doesn't work. Any ideas how to implement that without the deprecated methods?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky Attach the view to the NSStatusBarButton